# Unable to update Package Manager due to syntax error

Tags: package-management, hplip

I noticed my package manager was not updating and kept giving an error about third party repo's so I disabled them and tried to run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get update
```

However it seems the hplip package is not allowing me to do this. I get this error message from the terminal:

```
(Reading database ... 253351 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace hplip-data 3.13.9-1 (using .../hplip-data_3.13.9-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb) ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
except (IOError, OSError), e:
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
except (IOError, OSError), e:
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/hplip-data_3.13.9-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb (--unpack):
subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/hplip-data_3.13.9-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried deleting the .deb package from /var/cache/apt but it still gives the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the pyclean on my system to py3clean. This fixed the problem.

Comment: I fail to see the relation.